# What does "function" == typeof variable mean?

Tags: javascript

```
if ("function" == typeof type) {        
      msg = type;         
      type = "";
    }
```

I am quite new to Javascript. I've read Third party js book [http://thirdpartyjs.com/]. I am looking at few example codes to understand the logic. I've got struck at this part of script. My question is what's the function of this if statement? Why is function in "" . Does it mean the function is an object?.

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof

Comment: It checks if type of the `type` variable is equal to `"function"`, it's just written as *yoda condition* ;) Writing it as `if(typeof type == "function")` would probably be easier to read.

Comment: consider changing the question title to something more informative.

Comment: Sure thing. I'll change the title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what's the function of this if statement?

It checks whether the `type` variable is a function reference or not

> Why is function in ""

Because `typeof` always returns a string

> Does it mean the function is an object?

Functions are objects indeed, but I'm not sure what you mean by this question exactly.

Answer (score 2):

I wonder if the asker is perhaps caught up on the somewhat unintuitive 'reverse' comparison style.

```
if ("function" == typeof type) {
```

It is the same as:

```
if (typeof type  == "function" ) {
```

I.e. we are checking if the type of the variable named 'type' is "function".

As doldt already mentioned, typeof will return the type as a string, hence the quotes.